# What is the sum of reciprocal of product of $n$ primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, divisor-sum

**Question :** What is the sum of the series given below?

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} + \cdots \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot \cdots \cdot \sqrt{n}}$$

in the denominator these are the product of primes . What is the bound on this sum?

Is this $\le c\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ ? where $c$ is some constant I know the given sum above is $\le \sqrt{n}/2$ but I need a tighter bound.

Question 2: Is this series converges to constant ?

Comment: What *means* $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot\cdots\cdot\sqrt{n}$? $\sqrt{n}\in\Bbb N$ for only some $n$. Did you mean primes up to $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: @ Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla prime upto $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Maybe useful: for $n$ large enough $p_n\approx n\log n$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is $>1/2$. You can't have a bound that $\to 0$ like $c/\sqrt n$.

Answer for $2$: the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\prod_{k=1}^np_n}$$
is convergent by comparison with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n!}$:

$$\frac1{\prod_{k=1}^np_n}\le\frac1{n!}.$$